# Determine distance between two lines in an image

Tags: image-processing

I have the following image:

[image]

In this image there are 5 more or less vertical peaks in total. Let the x-axis be the horizontal axis and y-axis be the vertical axis. I would like to determine the distance between the center of the most intense peak (peak in the middle of the image) and the centers of the 4 symmetrically surrounding peaks for every given y-value. So that I know the distance of these peak-centers as a function of y.

For reasons of testing the code, I have selected a smaller area in the original image file:

[image: testlong]

Within my code this image is called: testlong.jpg

My code so far:

```
img2 = Import["filepath\\testlong.jpg"];
data2 = ImageData[img2];
Dimensions[data2]

For[column = 1, column < 83, column++, pc[column] =        
Position[data2[[All,  column]], Max[data2[[All, column]]]];
pb[column] = Position[data2[[1 ;; 60, column]], Max[data2[[1 ;; 60, 
column]]]];
pt[column] = 239 + Position[data2[[240 ;; 282, column]], Max[data2[[240 
;; 280, column]]]];];

For[lauf = 1, lauf < 83, lauf++, pcflat[lauf] = Flatten[pc[lauf]]];
For[lauf = 1, lauf < 83, lauf++, pbflat[lauf] = Flatten[pb[lauf]]];
For[lauf = 1, lauf < 83, lauf++, ptflat[lauf] = Flatten[pt[lauf]]];
```

Now what's to do is to plot pcflat, ptflat, pbflat, fit each one with a line of best fit and determine the distance between these lines. But I don't seem to be able to plot pcflat, ptflat, pbflat. If I use:

```
ListPlot[Table[pcflat[i],{i,1,82}],PlotRange->All]
```

*Mathematica* plots 3 points within the interval [1,2]

The problem is, that pcflat, pbflat, etc are nested lists with unequal length, because some x-values correspond with more than one y-value where there is a maximum (peaks are not delta peaks but have a width). How do I plot that?

Comment: For takers: Ausgleichsgerade == line of best fit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are looking for vertical lines, the problem is 1D. Start by summing the pixels for each column of the image:

```
img2 = Import["http://s4.postimg.org/dearql4iz/XZ_85.png"];
data2 = ImageData[img2];
sums = Map[Tr, Transpose@data2];
ListPlot[sums]
```

[image]

It seems the 5 five lines you are mentionning are not so clear. But we can see clearly three of them.

Using `FindPeaks` to find the positions of the lines, sorting them with respect to the second component and selecting the five first ones:

```
peaks = FindPeaks[sums];
selectedPeaks = Sort[peaks, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &][[1 ;; 5]] 
Show[ListPlot[sums, PlotRange -> Full], 
      ListPlot[selectedPeaks, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

```
Show[img2, Graphics[{Red, Dashed, Map[Line[{{#, 0}, {#, h}}] &, selectedPeaks[[All, 1]] ]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that great answer, in this code I do not even have to specify intervals around the peaks.

Answer (score 3):

There are some problems with the way you generate your data. The biggest one is that Position returns multiple locations because maximum pixel value happens more than once for one y-value. For example, from your code, if you look at pb[2], you'll get {{29}, {33}, {34}, {35}}. This means that the maximum value occurs four times in that column. The easiest way to fix this is to take the average of all the locations. Here's a working solution.

```
img2 = Import["C:\\Users\\labuser\\Downloads\\testlong.jpg"];
data2 = ImageData[img2];
Dimensions[data2];

For[column = 1, column < 83, column++, 
  pc[column] = 
   Mean[Flatten[
     Position[data2[[All, column]], Max[data2[[All, column]]]]]];
  pb[column] = 
   Mean[Flatten[
     Position[data2[[1 ;; 60, column]], 
      Max[data2[[1 ;; 60, column]]]]]];
  pt[column] = 
   Mean[Flatten[
     239 + Position[data2[[240 ;; 282, column]], 
       Max[data2[[240 ;; 280, column]]]]]]];
pbflat = Table[pb[i], {i, 1, 82}];
ptflat = Table[pt[i], {i, 1, 82}];
pcflat = Table[pc[i], {i, 1, 82}];
ListPlot[{pbflat, ptflat, pcflat}]
```

[image: Working plot]

After that, it's just a matter of fitting a line to each of the data set.

I haven't changed much of your code. There are things you could do that could make it much more efficient. For example, your code could be a lot faster by using Map/Scan/Apply instead of procedural programming, i.e. for loop. See this 10 tips for writing fast Mathematica code, item#9 for a comparison. Unfortunately, I can't post the link to this article because my reputation is not enough. (Tragedy). But a quick google of the article's name will turn it up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I especially like that you used my code and corrected it, that way it is easier for me to improve. Also thx for the literature tip.